# Facebook cannot retreive iPhone store ID

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store, facebook-ads-api

My app is live for 2 days now but I still cannot setup facebook iOS settings (Facebook Developer > MyApp > Settings > Basic > iOS). I receive below massage next to iPhone Store ID box.

> There was a problem retrieving your iPhone Store ID from the App
>   Store. Please check the ID and try again later.

Does anybody have any idea why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a 24 hours lasting issue. Just try it after a day.

Comment: Didn't you say your app had been live for 2 days? Do you mean it was resolved within 3 days from when your app was live?

Comment: My app was live for 2 days but when I setup facebook iOS settings it took 24 hours from that point.